# Where and How Bash convert strings to colors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ansi-colors

I am working on Bash 5.0 from [GNU repository](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tag/?h=bash-5.0). I wanted to find the place where Bash reads a string with ASCII colors and convert it to colors, like in the following case where it convert "Hello" to red:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# ./bash
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# echo $BASH_VERSION                                                         
5.0.0(8)-release
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# ./bash -c 'echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World"'
Hello World
```

I searched inside the source code and found two files that seems to be related:

1. `bash-5.0/lib/readline/colors.c` - [link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/colors.c?h=bash-5.0)
2. `bash-5.0/lib/readline/parse-colors.c` - [link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/parse-colors.c?h=bash-5.0)

But they are **not**, they work only on the first time I load Bash and you need to write the following rows in the file `~/.inputrc` for it to work:

```
set colored-completion-prefix on
set colored-stats on
```

Any idea where in the code Bash takes string like that `"\033[31mHello"` and convert it to red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the shell that's converting anything to colors, it is your *terminal*. The shell only outputs [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which are then picked up by the terminal.

Depending on your point of view and philosophical interpretations, `\033[31mHello` already **is** a colored string (for the shell, at least, it is)